# How can I create the shape of side mirrors of a truck/lorry?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

```css
.circle {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 20;
  border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 2px yellow;
}
.roof {
  width: 280px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: gray;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -2;
  position: relative;
}
.windscreen {
  width: 260px;
  height: 75px;
  background: rgb(41, 137, 216);
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 10%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1) 22%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 35%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1) 50%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 65%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1) 78%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 90%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(10%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1)), color-stop(22%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1)), color-stop(35%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1)), color-stop(65%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1)), color-stop(78%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1)), color-stop(90%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1)));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 10%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1) 22%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 35%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1) 50%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 65%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1) 78%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 90%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 10%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1) 22%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 35%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1) 50%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 65%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1) 78%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 90%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 10%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1) 22%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 35%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1) 50%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 65%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1) 78%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 90%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 10%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1) 22%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 35%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1) 50%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 65%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1) 78%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 90%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#2989d8', endColorstr='#2989d8', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
  margin-left: 10px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #000;
  /*not sure of this*/
}
.roof-bonnet {
  height: 320px;
  margin-top: -100px;
}
#numberplate {
  height: 40px;
  width: 190px;
  background-color: white;
  bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -45px;
  margin-left: 44px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  font-size: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.circle-headlight {
  margin-top: -55px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 2px white;
}
.right-headlight {
  margin-left: 238px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle" style="margin-left:240px;"></div>


<div class="roof"></div>

<div class="windscreen"></div>

<div class="roof roof-bonnet"></div>
<div class="circle circle-headlight"></div>
<div class="circle circle-headlight right-headlight"></div>
<div id="numberplate">REG PLATE</div>
```

I've been trying to generate a lorry/truck in CSS, but am having some difficulty generating the side mirrors, I think mainly due to my bad designing/use of `position`.

I currently have the above code, which generate the basic lorry shape (not complete by all means).

I would like to add something like:

```
         +-------+
|        |        \
|        |         |
|       /|         |
|      //|         |
|     // |         |
|    // /|         |
|   // //|         |
|  // // |_________/
--- +//
-----+  
|
|
```

To either side.

Would anyone have any suggestions as to adding this without 'breaking' the current pen?

---

So far I have tried to generate this shape, using:

```
#wing-mirror {
    margin-top:40px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    border-radius:20px;
}

#wing-mirror:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-top: 10px solid red;
    border-left: 29px solid #fff;
    border-right: 29px solid #fff;
    width: 42px;
    height: 0;
}
```

---

## After Many Attempts, and post writing this question,

---

i have created this 'wing mirror', but since I am using specific values, placing this 'next' to my lorry, the alignment breaks and so none of the 'bonnet/windscreen/roof align properly, no matter where i put this wing mirror in my html.

**My completed wing mirror looks like this:**

```css
#wing-mirror {
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: gray;
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  border-radius: 20px;
}
#wing-mirror:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-top: 10px solid gray;
  border-left: 29px solid #fff;
  border-right: 29px solid #fff;
  width: 42px;
  height: 0;
}
.border-div {
  width: 75px;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  margin-left: 30px;
}
.border-div-top {
  width: 50px;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wing-mirror"></div>
<div class="border-div"></div>
<div class="border-div-top"></div>
```

But how can I attach this into my overall lorry? As everything I've tried leads to 'jumpy' elements (they don't 'stick' to the lorry) and they don't align correctly to the side of the elements (the don't appear to left or right of the lorry, possibly due to bad implementation).

Comment: Can't you make something like`<div style="display: inline-block; background: gray;width: 40px;height: 60px;border-radius: 0 10px 15px 0;">
</div>` + you have to make windshield `inline-block;`

Comment: Is this some kind of exercise? This is really not what's CSS made for. Instead you would better use SVG, which is pretty easy to embedd in HTML.

Comment: no, it's not an exercise. It's a project for work. And CSS is designed for visual display/presentation. I've never used SVG, nor wish to. I've used css for all other shapes (see my prev. questions), and prefer it. So i'm using css (small, compact) and does the job.

Comment: you have somehow a missunderstanding of CSS... it's for styling of elements, not for drawing pictures. But go on. You will find out soon enough ;)

Comment: I think it's awesome people try things in languages/environments not designed for those specific tasks. Bring it on!

Comment: SVG has arguably even smaller spec than CSS3. Usually you won't need more than 5-6 tags anyway.

Comment: You asked something else, you selected something else

Comment: @Mr.Alien: Could you please clarify?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because whilst it was an interesting shape to create, I feel it is not worth keeping on the site as it does suggest CSS is the correct tool for making such shapes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> **Disclaimer:** I don't believe this approach is the best to create the shape you are after. Depending on your use case, you should look into [SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG) or a normal png/jpeg.

I added one element for each mirror and used skewed pseudo elements with borders on the `.windscreen` div for the mirror arms.

To position the mirrors, I added `position:relative;` to the `.windscreen` div and inserted the mirrors as a children of that div. This way you can use absolute positioning to put the mirror on the left and right relatively to the windscreen.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/7pxLn7b9/)**

```css
body{
    padding-left:100px;
}
.circle {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 20;
  border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 2px yellow;
}
.roof {
  width: 280px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: gray;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -2;
  position: relative;
}
.windscreen {
    position:relative;
  width: 260px;
  height: 75px;
  background: rgb(41, 137, 216);
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 10%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1) 22%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 35%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1) 50%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 65%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1) 78%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 90%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(10%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1)), color-stop(22%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1)), color-stop(35%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1)), color-stop(65%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1)), color-stop(78%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1)), color-stop(90%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1)));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 10%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1) 22%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 35%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1) 50%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 65%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1) 78%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 90%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 10%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1) 22%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 35%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1) 50%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 65%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1) 78%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 90%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 10%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1) 22%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 35%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1) 50%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 65%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1) 78%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 90%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 10%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1) 22%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 35%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1) 50%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 65%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1) 78%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 90%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#2989d8', endColorstr='#2989d8', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
  margin-left: 10px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #000;
  /*not sure of this*/
}
.roof-bonnet {
  height: 320px;
  margin-top: -100px;
}
#numberplate {
  height: 40px;
  width: 190px;
  background-color: white;
  bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -45px;
  margin-left: 44px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  font-size: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.circle-headlight {
  margin-top: -55px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 2px white;
}
.right-headlight {
  margin-left: 238px;
}
.windscreen:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    left:100%; bottom:15px;
    width:10px; height:20px;
    transform:skewX(-30deg);
    border-bottom:12px solid #000;
    border-right: 12px solid #000;
    z-index:-1;
}
.windscreen:before{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    right:100%; bottom:15px;
    width:10px; height:20px;
    transform:skewX(30deg);
    border-bottom:12px solid #000;
    border-left: 12px solid #000;
    z-index:-1;
}
.mirror{
    position:absolute;
    left:100%; top:20px;
    margin-left:19px;
    height: 30px;
    width:20px;
    background:#000;
}

.mirror:before, .mirror:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    bottom:100%;
    border-color: #000 transparent;
    border-width: 0 5px 10px 0;
    border-style:solid;
}
.mirror:after{
    bottom:auto;
    top:100%;
    border-width: 7px 3px 0 0;
}
.mirrorL{
    position:absolute;
    right:100%; top:20px;
    margin-right:19px;
    height: 30px;
    width:20px;
    background:#000;
}

.mirrorL:before, .mirrorL:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    bottom:100%;
    border-color: #000 transparent;
    border-width: 0 0 10px 5px;
    border-style:solid;
}
.mirrorL:after{
    bottom:auto;
    top:100%;
    border-width: 7px 0 0 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle" style="margin-left:240px;"></div>


<div class="roof"></div>

<div class="windscreen"><div class="mirror"></div><div class="mirrorL"></div></div>

<div class="roof roof-bonnet"></div>
<div class="circle circle-headlight"></div>
<div class="circle circle-headlight right-headlight"></div>
<div id="numberplate">REG PLATE</div>
```

Comment: Your actual shape is a lot stronger @web-tiki, but it's quite difficult to replicate it for the left hand side (due to my bad design)

Comment: @jbutler483 BTW, your lorry shape can be very much optimized by for example removing elements and using pseudo elements instead.

Comment: i'm sure from my previous questions (most of which you've answered teehee), you can tell i'm not the most proficient in css styling. But i've started looking at pseudo elements, and am **slowly** incorporating them into my css sheets.

Answer (score 14):

Something like this?

I would strongly advise you to use a relatively positioned parent to contain your lorry. I would then use percentage based units to size and position the elements so that the width and the height of the parent can change but the shape inside scales.

The example uses a relatively positioned parent so that all the child elements can be positioned relative to the parent rather than the body. I've also changed everything to percentage based widths and positions so that when you change the width and the height of the parent, the lorry will scale inside it.

```css
#lorry2 {
 position: relative;
 width: 260px;
 height: 320px;
 float: left;
}
#lorry2 .roof {
 height: 20%;
 background-color: gray;
 border-top-left-radius: 50%;
 border-top-right-radius: 50%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
}
#lorry2 .windscreen {
 height: 20%;
 background: rgb(41, 137, 216);
 /* Old browsers */
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 10%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1) 22%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 35%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1) 50%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 65%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1) 78%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 90%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 100%);
 /* FF3.6+ */
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(10%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1)), color-stop(22%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1)), color-stop(35%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1)), color-stop(65%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1)), color-stop(78%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1)), color-stop(90%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1)));
 /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 10%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1) 22%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 35%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1) 50%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 65%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1) 78%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 90%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 100%);
 /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
 background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 10%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1) 22%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 35%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1) 50%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 65%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1) 78%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 90%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 100%);
 /* Opera 11.10+ */
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 10%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1) 22%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 35%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1) 50%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 65%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1) 78%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 90%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 100%);
 /* IE10+ */
 background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 10%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1) 22%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 35%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1) 50%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 65%, rgba(170, 170, 170, 1) 78%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 90%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1) 100%);
    /* W3C */
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#2989d8', endColorstr='#2989d8', GradientType=1);
 /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #000;/*not sure of this*/
 position: absolute;
 top: 20%;
 left: 4%;
 right: 4%;
 z-index: 5;
}
#lorry2 .bonnet {
    background-color: gray;
 border-top-left-radius: 50%;
 border-top-right-radius: 50%;
 height: 86%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 14%;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
}
#lorry2 #numberplate {
 height: 10%;
 background-color: white;
 bottom: 10px;
 position: relative;
 border: 2px solid black;
 font-size: auto;
 text-align: center;
 position: absolute;
 top: 80%;
 left: 15%;
 right: 15%;
}
#lorry2 .headLight {
 position: absolute;
 top: 81%;
 left: 1%;
 width: 13%;
 padding-top: 13%;
 height: 0;
 background-color: white;
 font-size: auto;
 text-align: center;
 z-index: 1;
 border-radius: 50%;
 box-shadow: 0 0 8px 2px #fff;
}
#lorry2 .headLight.right {
 left: auto;
 right: 1%;
}
#lorry2 .fullBeam {
 position: absolute;
 top: 3%;
 left: 1%;
 width: 13%;
 padding-top: 13%;
 height: 0;
 background-color: yellow;
 font-size: auto;
 text-align: center;
 z-index: 1;
 border-radius: 50%;
 box-shadow: 0 0 8px 2px yellow;
}
#lorry2 .fullBeam.right {
 left: auto;
 right: 1%;
}
#lorry2 .wingMirror.left {
 position: absolute;
 width: 15%;
 height: 0;
 padding-top: 15%;
 top: 25%; 
 left: -11%;
}
#lorry2 .wingMirror.right {
 position: absolute;
 width: 15%;
 height: 0;
 padding-top: 15%;
 top: 25%;
 right: -11%;
}
#lorry2 .wingMirror.right .barBottom {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 background: #828282;
 width: 42%;
 height: 20%;
}
#lorry2 .wingMirror.right .barDiagonal {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 23%;
 left: 20%;
 background: #828282;
 width: 62%;
 height: 20%;
 -moz-transform: rotate(-60deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(-60deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(-60deg);
 transform: rotate(-60deg);
}
#lorry2 .wingMirror.right .mirror {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 15%;
 left: 58%;
 height: 100%;
 width: 60%;
 background: #828282;
 -webkit-border-radius:  0 30% 30% 0;
 border-radius: 0 30% 30% 0;
}
#lorry2 .wingMirror.left .barBottom {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 background: #828282;
 width: 42%;
 height: 20%;
}
#lorry2 .wingMirror.left .barDiagonal {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 23%;
 right: 20%;
 background: #828282;
 width: 62%;
 height: 20%;
 -moz-transform: rotate(60deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(60deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(60deg);
 transform: rotate(60deg);
}
#lorry2 .wingMirror.left .mirror {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 15%;
 right: 58%;
 height: 100%;
 width: 60%;
 background: #828282;
 -webkit-border-radius: 30% 0 0 30%;
 border-radius: 30% 0 0 30%;
}
```

```html
<div id="lorry2">
 <div class="fullBeam left"></div>
 <div class="fullBeam right"></div>
 <div class="roof"></div>
 <div class="windscreen"></div>
 <div class="bonnet"></div>
 <div class="headLight left"></div>
 <div class="headLight right"></div>
 <div id="numberplate">REG PLATE</div>
 <div class="wingMirror left">
  <div class="barBottom"></div>
  <div class="barDiagonal"></div>
  <div class="mirror"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="wingMirror right">
  <div class="barBottom"></div>
  <div class="barDiagonal"></div>
  <div class="mirror"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've been trying to manipulate your example to having 'chiselled' corners, but without success. other than that, it seems pretty spot on tbh!

Comment: I suggest you use a clip-path to make the shape you desire:http://cssplant.com/clip-path-generator