# Glowing effect on orb/sphere/ball/globe in css

Tags: html, css

I have been attempting to make a glowing effect on a sphere in terms of internal 'shiny sphere' patterns, but have become stuck with the likes of positioning some aspects of the 'globe'.

As it currently stands, my css looks like:

```css
.sphere {


  height: 200px;


  width: 200px;


  background-color: red;


  border-radius: 50%;


  text-align: center;


  vertical-align: middle;


  line-height: 200px;


  box-shadow: inset -10px -10px 100px #000, 10px 10px 20px black, inset 0px 0px 10px black;


}


.sphere::after {


  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);


  content: '';


  height: 15%;


  width: 2%;


  position: absolute;


  top: 0.25%;


  left: 3%;


  border-radius: 50%;


  transform: rotate(45deg);


}


.sphere2 {


  height: 200px;


  width: 200px;


  background-color: yellow;


  border-radius: 50%;


  text-align: center;


  vertical-align: middle;


  line-height: 200px;


  box-shadow: inset -10px -10px 100px #000, 10px 10px 20px black, inset 0px 0px 10px black;


}


.shine {


  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);


  content: '';


  height: 50%;


  width: 15%;


  left: 18%;


  top: 0%;


  position: relative;


  border-radius: 50%;


  transform: rotate(45deg);


}
```

```html
<div class="sphere">High Importance</div>



<div class="sphere2">
  <div class="shine"></div>
  Important


</div>
```

[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/jbutler483/pen/VYjwxO)

But the 'shine' effect on either sphere won't 'stay' in place. (Neither attempts full work).

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction as to position these correctly (in the top left hand side, with a small margin)?

This will hopefully/eventually look similar to [this](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3BouncingBall/) (without the animated effect, that is)

Any advice would be much appreciated at this point (and i hope you can see where i'm going with this design, as i wish for it to be dynamically sized).

Comment: I feel something like this is an abuse of CSS, you're better off doing this as SVG artwork set as a `background-image` in CSS or `<img />` in HTML.

Comment: @Dai: it's what I do. [Here's another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27355331/creating-a-truck-lorry-shape-in-css) previous question I had. I will say again what i said then, I've never used SVG, (hope) never to, and prefer css (esp. when I've only really started testing the water with it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remember when you use `absolute` position you need to define the `relative` parent to position, this will be the closest with a non-static position defined. Try:

```
.sphere{
  position:relative;
}
.sphere::after{
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  content:'';
  height:50%;
  width: 15%;
  left:18%;
  top:0%;
  position:absolute;
  border-radius:50%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

**[Codepen Updated](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxBYJL)**

Comment: thank you @Danko: but could you possibly clarify what you mean by *the closest with a non-static position*

Comment: Of course @jbutler483 maybe this can clarify a little bit ...... For default all elements value position is static when you use absolute the values for left top right ... are relative to some other element, in this case it searchs for the parent if this doesn't have a position value defined different from static then gets to the next parent and again and again until he finds one with a position val different from static.

Comment: @jbutler483 to clarify maybe this http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/ and http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/

Comment: in terms of scalability: If i was to make these smaller, obviously the shadows/text/etc. will go out of proportion (i'm not sure, but guessing this will also impace the after pseudo effect). is there a way of combatting this to 'scale' both bigger and smaller?

Comment: @jbutler483 the after element will remain scaled since it's defined based on % values of the parent but the text and the shadow will present issues... if it is so necessary the option could be use transform scale property.. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azZzdx

Answer (score 1):

Position your `.sphere` and `.sphere2` relatively and the `::after` :pseudo-elements absolutely and give them same `top` and `left` values.

### [codepen](http://codepen.io/chipChocolate/pen/OPXJBN)

```css
.sphere {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 200px;
  box-shadow: inset -10px -10px 100px #000, 10px 10px 20px black, inset 0px 0px 10px black;
}
.sphere::after,
.sphere2::after {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  content: '';
  height: 40%;
  width: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8%;
  left: 14%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.sphere2 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 200px;
  box-shadow: inset -10px -10px 100px #000, 10px 10px 20px black, inset 0px 0px 10px black;
}
.sphere2::after {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="sphere">High Importance</div>
<div class="sphere2">
  <div class="shine"></div>
  Important
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for my bad pen deisgn, they were two different tests to get it working properly! :P. So the main problem really was my positioning of `relatively/absolutely`? that always seems to be getting me mixed up!

Comment: @jbutler483  - Yes that was the problem. Always position your main element `relative`ly and :pseudo-element `absolutely`.

Comment: That's the one issue with codepen. Once you edit it, the link doesn't change (link in question has updated to my 'new' pen :(()